# Find the deepest file/directory in the tree, Java

Tags: java, file, nested

I have a directory (`basedir3645`) containing a lot of nested directories and files (almost 40 000). Each nested directory may contain a few files and directories. The problem is to find the deepest file or directory (the method must return the nesting level of the deepest item and its name/path.

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String pathToDir = "D:\\Dropbox\\java\\tasks\\basedir3645";
        File baseDir = new File(pathToDir);
        System.out.println(findDeepestItem(baseDir));   
    }

    static public String findDeepestItem(File folder) {
        int currentLevel = 0;
        int deepestLevel = 0;
        String deepestItem = "";
        String result = "";
        File[] folderEntries = folder.listFiles();
        for (File entry : folderEntries) {
            currentLevel = countMatches(entry.getPath(), "\\");
            if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                findDeepestItem(entry);
                if (deepestLevel < currentLevel) {
                    deepestLevel = currentLevel;
                    deepestItem = entry.getPath();
                }
                continue;
            } else {
                if (deepestLevel < currentLevel) {
                    deepestLevel = currentLevel;
                    deepestItem = entry.getPath();
                }
            }
        }
        result = String.valueOf(deepestLevel) + " " + deepestItem;
        return result;
    }

    private static int countMatches(String path, String string) {
        int number = 0;
        String[] array = path.split("");
        for (int i = 0; i < path.length(); i++) {
            if (string.contentEquals(array[i])) {
                number++;
            }
        }
        return number;
    }
}
```

Here I determine the nesting level of current item (file or directory) by counting the number of `\` occurencies in item `getPath()`.

The program passes through all the element in tree (I've checked it, using `System.out.println("entry.getPath()");` in loop, but it cannot count he deepest nesting level.

Comment: Can't you use `java.nio` and especially `Path.getNameCount()` in order to determine the depth level of a filesystem object in the file tree? Maybe use a `java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor` to traverse the file tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood where is my mistake - the variables `deepestLevel` and `deepestItem` must be static and belong to class.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static class Pair {
    int depth;
    String name;

    Pair(int depth, String name) {
        this.depth = depth;
        this.name = name;
    }
}

public static Pair depthFirstSearch(File root) {
    if(root.isFile() || root.listFiles().length == 0) {
        return new Pair(1, root.getName());
    }

    File[] files = root.listFiles();
    Pair maxForThisNode = new Pair(-1, "");
    for(int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        Pair childPair = depthFirstSearch(files[i]);
        if(childPair.depth > maxForThisNode.depth) {
            maxForThisNode.depth = childPair.depth;
            maxForThisNode.name = childPair.name;
        }
    }

    maxForThisNode.depth += 1;
    return maxForThisNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't just return the *name* of the deepest item but also the level. For this you will have to

- pass the current level to `findDeepestItem` and
- return a result object containing the name and the level.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {

    String dirName = "";
    int deepFile = 0;
    int permDeep = 0;

    public String getFiles(File files) {
        for (File file : files.listFiles()) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                permDeep++;
                getFiles(file);
                if (permDeep > deepFile) {
                    deepFile = permDeep;
                    dirName = file.getName();
                }
                permDeep--;
            } else {
                if (permDeep > deepFile) {
                    deepFile = permDeep;
                    dirName = file.getName();
                }
            }
        }
        return dirName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CompareHolder holder = new CompareHolder();
        Files.walk(Path.of(args[0]))
                .map(Path::toFile)
                .filter(File::isFile)
                .forEach(file -> holder.compare(file.getName(), file.getPath().split("/").length));
        System.out.printf("The longest depth is %d and the file name is %s %n", holder.depth, holder.name);
    }

    static class CompareHolder {
        String name;
        int depth;

        void compare(String name, int depth) {
            if (depth > this.depth) {
                this.depth = depth;
                this.name = name;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding some explanation to how the code you have shown solves the problem, and how it is better than (or different from) other answers would significantly improve this post.

Answer (score 0):

Below my solution. It is similar to the answer from denamyte but without the conversation to a `java.io.File`.

I used `Files.walk()` and the `Path.getNameCount()` method to determine the deepest file  starting at a given path. The `s.map(p::relativize)` ensures, that the deepth of the starting directory is ignored.

The return object is a `java.nio.file.Path` so it provides every information you should need.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path p = Paths.get("C:\\anypath");
        Optional<Path> deepest = findDeepest(p);
        if (deepest.isPresent()) {
            Path pdeep = deepest.get();
            boolean isFile = Files.isRegularFile(p.resolve(pdeep));
            System.out.printf("level: %d, isfile: %s, path %s", pdeep.getNameCount() - (isFile ? 1 : 0), isFile, pdeep);
        } else
            System.err.println("no files found");
    }

    public static Optional<Path> findDeepest(Path p) throws IOException {
        try (Stream<Path> s = Files.walk(p)) {
            return s.filter(Files::isRegularFile).map(p::relativize).max(Comparator.comparing(Path::getNameCount));
        }
    }

}
```